# Can a manual/hand impact driver be used with sockets?

Tags: impact-wrench, driver, socket

[image: impact socket set with manual impact driver]
Manual/hand impact drivers are usually described for use with impact (screwdriver) bits. But can they be used with hex sockets too?

I realize that typically an electric or air impact driver/wrench would be used for sockets, but it would be good to know if the manual driver can also be used in a pinch.

Is it ok, is the manual impact driver simply not able to deliver enough torque, or is it even likely to be damaged by such use?

Comment: Where did you get the picture from?

Comment: @HandyHowie Clicking on the image will navigate to the vendor's product page where the image is from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and they can work well.

Often got me out of a situation long ago before all these cordless things appeared and I was out in a remote field.

And a large hammer tends to make them work - as long as the piece that the nut, or bolt, is on does not deform...

However, I also found that using a bar and alternately trying to tighten then loosen the nut or bolt would work as well.

Comment: Is there a general notion of how tightly torqued or how large a nut a manual impact driver can be used for? The instruction manual makes no mention except for stating to "use less than 3lb of force when striking to extend the product's useful life." Yes, breaker bars are also very useful but sometimes there just isn't enough space.

Comment: My impact driver had no such instructions... but it was / is by Snap On... As for breaker bars, I have knuckle bars and T bars as well as diamond e tensions to get angles.

Comment: I didn't find instructions or specifications for Snap-on's hand impact drivers (PIT120 3/8" drive, PIT160 1/2" drive), and most of their kits just come with bits, but I did find a couple of sets that include hex sockets, oddly only for the 3/8" unit, eg: https://shop.snapon.com/product/supplemental/36-pc-3-8%22-Drive-Impact-Driver-Set/PIT2230E I find it strange how difficult it is to find any information combining hand impact drivers and hex sockets, but at least if Snap-on sells a set of them together, it's not contraindicated, at least for their model.